# Attribute Paint node is missing from Houdini, how can I access it?

Tags: nodes, houdini

I'm using Houdini Apprentice, and though there are certain limitations with that there doesn't seem to be any mention of losing access to that particular node with this version. Other attributes are available: blur, composite, noise, promote, etc. Just no Attribute Paint.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What specific version of Houdini are you using?

Comment: 17.5, yes and I now know this node was added only in 18, as I was told on another thread. Thank you for helping me along though!

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to contain the specific version of Houdini you are using, and add an answer saying that the node is only available in Houdini 18. It may serve useful to others with the same issue.